# getpass python3 no input

Tags: python-3.x, getpass

```
existing_users = {
        'adam' : 'Test123'
        }
unverified_users = []

status = ""
status = input("If you have an account, type YES, NO to create a new user, QUIT to exit: ")
status = status.lower()
max_attempts = 2
import getpass
while status != 'quit':

    if status == 'yes':
        usr_name = input("Please provide your username: ")
        usr_pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter the password")
```

I can't get getpass to work, not sure what I'm doing wrrong. If I run the code I'm prompted for the user name and then nothing else happens ....

any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you running this through IDLE by any chance?

Comment: I'm using Spyder

Comment: Is that with the ipython console? (sorry, I'm not familiar with spyder, so i'm going by what i can find).

Comment: Also, when prompted for the username, can you enter the username and then it doesn't show the password question, or you can't enter anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to do with the spyder having a separate console to the one getpass uses. Try it in your regular console next time you run it. It might appear. But if you want to run it all through the spyder console, you'll need to use something else like input() for the password.

(I tried it in my own console - changed a little for python 2 - and it works fine. So I'm pretty certain it's the console you're using)